# Alembic - how to create hypertable

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, alembic, timescaledb, sqlmodel

How to generate hypertable using Alembic? Some custom call must be added I suppose, but where? I tried event.listen but Alembic does not register it.

Comment: Timescale does not have any special support. What exactly are you trying to do?
See this issue with some old sample from people that are using it with alembic:
https://github.com/timescale/timescaledb/issues/551

Also, the timescale quickstart shows that you can use plain sql for most of the calls: https://docs.timescale.com/timescaledb/latest/quick-start/python/

Comment: I am creating tables using SQLAlchemy and after table creation I want to also create a hypertable so I am looking for a way to automatically generate Alembic migration that would create the hypertable.

Comment: I'd suggest you come to alembic framework and find a developer that can build it for you, or build it yourself. I'm not a python expert to help here, but probably you can achieve it building a kind of extension/plugin for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create hypertables in Alembic by adding manual, custom, migration actions.

You cannot generate it automatically, because there is no specific support in Alembic for TimescaleDB and it does not understand hypertables.

Answer (score 0):

```
def upgrade() -> None:
    op.create_table(
        TABLE_NAME,
        sa.Column('ts', sa.DateTime),
        sa.Column('col1', sa.String(50)),
        sa.Column('col2', sa.String(50)),
        sa.Column('col3',sa.String(50)),
        sa.Column('col4',sa.String(50)),
        sa.Column('col5',sa.Integer),
        sa.Column('col6',sa.Integer),
        schema=SCHEMA,
        if_not_exists=True,)

    op.execute(f"SELECT create_hypertable('{SCHEMA}.{TABLE_NAME}', 'ts');")
```

This worked for me. Make sure you create the hypertable extension if needed or you'll get errors.:

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS timescaledb CASCADE;
```